# Ip of the visitor

Tags: php

I have a php script that I use for a few weeks and that allows me to capture the ip of the person who visits my website, but since a few days (I have the impression that since That I activated the option "CDN + HTTP/2" on my hostserver OVH) that my script returns me one of the multiple public ip address of my web host OVH.

Here's the script:

```
    function get_ip() {
        if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        }
        elseif (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        }
        elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_COMING_FROM')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_COMING_FROM');
        }
        elseif (getenv('HTTP_VIA')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_VIA');
        }
        elseif (getenv('HTTP_XROXY_CONNECTION')) {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_XROXY_CONNECTION');
        }
        else {
            $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        }
        return $ip;
    }

    $ip = get_ip();
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can just dump it all and see what is wrong.

Comment: I put getenv ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') at the end and it works ... thanks;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solution.

```
function get_ip() {
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_COMING_FROM')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_COMING_FROM');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_VIA')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_VIA');
    }
    elseif (getenv('HTTP_XROXY_CONNECTION')) {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_XROXY_CONNECTION');
    }
    elseif (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {
        $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    }
    else {
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ip = get_ip();
```